# Least memory usage and best performance

Tags: rust

I need to store a billion "appearances" and I am looking for the most efficient way to store these with respect to both memory usage and performance. What are, for example, the differences in those respects for `a1, a2, a3` in:

```
struct Appearance<'a> {
    identity:   &'a u64, 
    role:       &'a str
}

struct AnotherAppearance<'a>((&'a u64, &'a str));

fn main() {
    let thing = 42;
    let hair_color = "hair color";
    let a1 = Appearance {identity: &thing, role: &hair_color};
    let a2 = AnotherAppearance((&thing, &hair_color));
    let a3 = (&thing, &hair_color);
}
```

Are there better ways to work with such a structure? Also, is there a way to get detailed information about `a1, a2, a3` so that I could see how they are represented in memory for myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, as Ijedrz noted, all your proposed alternatives have the same size.  In fact, from the compiler's point of view, they're all *identical*.

If you're after smaller memory sizes, you might be better off using something like:

```
struct Appearance {
    identity: u32,
    role: InternedString,
}
```

First of all, `u32` has 4 billion distinct values, so you definitely don't need a `u64` for a billion records.  Aside from that, a `&u64` is going to be the same size as a `u64` on a 64-bit machine, so there's not much point in using it.  That a `u32` is half the size is a bonus.

Beyond that, `&str` seems incredibly wasteful.  That's going to take two pointers for data which, I assume, is unlikely to change much.  If there are many more `Appearance`s than roles, your best bet is to intern the strings and reduce the field to a pointer (or even better: a `u32` ID which indirects through another table).  There is no interned string in the standard library, but they're not that hard to implement, assuming you can't find one somewhere.  Such a structure (assuming `InternedString` is a `u32` ID) would be 8 bytes versus your 24 bytes.

If performance is what you're after, that depends on *how* you use the structures.  That said, `&u64` is slower than `u64`, so changing that will probably help.  As for the string, it depends on how you use it.  If you mostly do comparisons, an interned string will be faster because you can compare *those* with a single comparison; comparing regular strings can be much slower since you have to actually look at the contents.

Comment: Brilliant, I can even use an u16 as a lookup key for the roles, since they are not that numerous. Theoretically, the u64 is owned by the "Keeper of Identities" and I figured a reference would reflect this behaviour in the code. I suppose the tradeoff is that if the Appearance owns its own u64 the compiler will not complain if an instance is created that the Keeper is not aware of? When you say 'slower' for a &u64, how much slower are we talking about?

Comment: @LarsRönnbäck: I don't know how much slower, but in order to look at or use the value, you'll have to do a deref and look elsewhere in memory.  Keeping things local means less cache thrashing.  Like almost all perf-related questions, it depends on your specific situation.

Answer (score 4):

All three variants seem to have the same size:

```
use std::mem::size_of;

println!("a1: {}", size_of::<Appearance>());        // a1: 24
println!("a2: {}", size_of::<AnotherAppearance>()); // a2: 24
println!("a3: {}", size_of::<(&u64, &str)>());      // a3: 24
```

So I would just use the one that is most descriptive, i.e. `Appearance`.